# GCP Cloud Identity account creation - Domain Not Found

Tags: google-cloud-identity

Trying to sign-up for Cloud Identity but get hit the following error message;

[What's your business's domain name?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d6cu.png)

What does "There was an error finding your domain." really mean - what is it really looking for?

I am using a domain hosted by google domains currently not pointing at anything but with valid SOA and NS records.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Reviewing my domain transfer from an external provider to google domains I uncovered a custom resource record had been automatically created on the google side.

This was a CNAME to the original providers parking domain.

Removing this reference allowed me to move on! :)